# WinAPI: Are waitable timers resumed after a sleep state?

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-c++

I read the [msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/kernel/system-sleeping-states) about sleeping states and software resumption and I was wondering:

- Are waitable timers always resumed after a sleep state?
- Could it be good practice to interrupt the scheduled actions by handling the power-management events? E.g. **WM_POWERBROADCAST**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. According to [System Wake-up Events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/power/system-wake-up-events), Your application can restore a computer that is in a sleep state to the working state by using a scheduled timer or a device event. This is known as a wake-up event. Use a [waitable timer object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Sync/waitable-timer-objects) to specify the time at which the system should wake.
2. According to [Operational Mode Events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/power/system-power-management-events#operational-mode-events), When an application receives notification that the system is about to enter sleep, it should perform any necessary operations quickly and return out of the message loop. The system allows for a maximum of two seconds per application when handling this message before timing out. So It's good practice to interrupt the scheduled actions by handling **some** power-management events.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What I mean by the first question is whether by having an action scheduled every N minutes, sleep events can break this loop. I.e. upon any sleep / wake-up this loop is resumed anyway?

Comment: @wmi As far as I am concerned, a waitable timer object  can restore a computer that is in a sleep state to the working state and vice versa. I test it and it seems that the system sleep time is **not** included in timer's `duetime`.